# Merge Pandas DataFrame where Values are not exactly alike

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two DataFrames:
First one (sp_df)

```
X   Y  density   keep  mass  size
10  20    33     False    23    23
3   2     52     True     5     5
1.2 3     35     False    25    52
```

Second one (ep_df)

```
X      Y     density  keep  mass  size
2.1   1.1      55     True   4.0   4.4
1.1   2.9      60     False  24.8  54.8
9.0   25.0     33     False  22.0  10.0
```

now i need to merge them with their X/Y Position into something like this:

```
X-SP Y-SP density-SP ........ X-EP Y-EP density-EP......
 1.5  2.0    30                1.0  2.4    28.7
```

So with the Data shown above you would get something like this:

```
X-SP   Y-SP  density-SP   keep-SP  mass-SP  size-SP X-EP  Y-EP    density-EP  keep-EP  mass-EP  size-EP
3       2       52          True     5         5     2.1   1.1      55        True       4.0      4.4
1.2     3       35          False    25       52     1.1   2.9      60        False      24.8     54.8
10      20      33          False    23       23     9.0  25.0      33        False      22.0     10.0
```

My Problem is now that those values are not frequently alike. So I need some kind comparison what two columns in the different dataframes are most likely to be the same. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can get this done.
Any Tips, advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: `So i need some kind comparison what two columns in the different dataframes are most likely to be the same.` Please define the logic you wish to implement to determine whether 2 rows are alike.

Comment: The X and Y values are as near as possible to each other. Then i consider the 2 rows alike

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but can you formulate `as near as possible to each other` (preferably with a formula)? Are we talking about rounding errors, e.g. 1.0 vs 1.00001 ?

Comment: For example i have in df1 a row with X/Y: 1.0/2.0 now i need to find in df2 a row where X/Y are as near as possible to to the 1.0/2.0, so it could be something like 1.5/2.0 or something like 2.0/1.0 or in the worst case it could be 10.0/5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can merge the two dataframes like a cartesian product. This will make a dataframe with each row of first data frame joined with every row of second data frame. Than remove the rows which have more difference between X values of the two dataframes. Hope the following code helps,

```
import pandas as pd
#cartesian_product
sp_df['key'] = 1
ep_df['key'] = 1
df = pd.merge(sp_df, ep_df, on='key', suffixes=['_sp', '_ep'])
del df['key']

##  taking difference and removing rows 
##  with difference more than 1
df['diff'] = df['X_sp'] - df['X_ep']
drop=df.index[df["diff"] >= 1].tolist()
df=df.drop(df.index[drop])
df
```

Edited code:

```
#cartesian_product
sp_df['key'] = 1
ep_df['key'] = 1
df = pd.merge(sp_df, ep_df, on='key', suffixes=['_sp', '_ep'])
del df['key']

##  taking difference and removing rows 
##  with difference more than 1
df['diff'] = df['X_sp'] - df['X_ep']
drop=df.index[df["diff"] >= 1.01].tolist()
drop_negative=df.index[df["diff"] <= 0 ].tolist()
droped_values=drop+drop_negative
df=df.drop(df.index[droped_values])
df
```

Comment: with your code and the data from above i get this result    
X_sp  Y_sp  ...  X_ep  Y_ep    
3      2         2.1   1.1  
3      2          9    25  
1.2    3         2.1   1.1  
1.2    3         1.1   2.9   
1.2    3          9    25

Comment: Sorry, this was because I didn't considered negative values in the difference. Please check the edited code above.
It also depends on what the tolerance level between the difference in two X values is okay for you. You can see the allowed difference in the code here is randomly selected to be 1.01.